# The most minimum required version of jQuery

Tags: jquery, methods, compression, extract

I know there is a difference between the jQuery's `document.ready()` and the native `javascript onload()` method, and as a result I would like to use `document.ready()` to do some initialize stuff while the `DOM` is ready.

However, I don't need any extra that provided by the jQuery library. Given the size of jQuery-1.7.2.min.js is *94.8kb*, which potentially may delay the loading time especially on mobile device, is there a way get an even compressed version of jQuery which only provides the `document.ready()` method?

If not, is there any other lib can provide similar functions?

Also, I know there is a mobile version of jQuery, but since this page will cater for both pc and mobile device, I am not sure if the mobile version will work well on pc. I guess if it is compatible then probably this is the way to go?

Thank you!

Comment: When you compress the minified version it becomes 32kB btw

Comment: May I ask what is the way of your compress? I guess 32kb is relatively acceptable comparing to the original 94.8k

Comment: You can either configure your server to return the contents using gzip encoding where available or choose one of the several CDN hosted solutions: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Comment: If you include your scripts at the end of the body (just before the `</body>` tag) they will execute with much the same timing as with document ready - without the need to include even a cut-down version of jQuery.

Comment: Our server is on AppEngine, so it automatically supports gzip encoding. However, this means unsupported browser (though very very rare) will still have to face the full size. I just had a peak of the gzip size, it is indeed about 34kb. I totally forgot about the gzip before I ask this question. Thanks!

Comment: @nnnnnn I know the Yahoo! recommendation of put js files at the end of the body. But how do I get it to be executed? I am not a front-end guy so please bear with me but I only know to use jquery's document.ready() or onLoad() on the body method to invoke a method once dom is loade. Is there another way to let the code executed?

Answer (score 6):

You might want to take a look at Zepto.js, it's only 8.4k...

http://zeptojs.com/

From their site -- "Zepto is a minimalist JavaScript library for modern browsers with a largely jQuery-compatible API. If you use jQuery, you already know how to use Zepto."

As far as IE support, there is a fallback you can use in IE to revert back to jQuery...

```
<script>
document.write('<script src=' +
('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery') +
'.js><\/script>')
</script>
```

Comment: +1 nice, never heard of it before, I will check that one out myself too!

Comment: A brief read of the website looks like it doesn't support IE officially. Probabaly I need to run some more tests to confirm our minimum code will run ok with zeptojs. But yep, this looks like a cool tool.

Comment: I've not used it much myself, I just know that Backbone.js which I do use often is also compatible with it since jQuery and Zepto have a similar API.

Comment: I've tested Zepto, looks like there is some complaining from IE. Obviously Zepto is not a fan of IE, which means I have to look somewhere else. But yep, thanks for sharing this interesting tool.

Comment: They list a fallback for IE on their docs that I added to the answer if that helps at all...

Answer (score 3):

Use a CDN for your script so that the script library gets cached. Here's a script for CDN + a fallback script when the CDN is unavailable.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Some of the benefits of using a CDN

- Lower bandwidth
- Scripts are cached
- Even small script files downloaded thousands of times will start to take a noticeable hit on your bandwidth meter.
- Less connections/hits to your web server which gives better latency

Comment: Agreed, I like the Zepto idea from jcreamer too, will be checking into it :-)

Comment: Sorry, I navigated away and came back and did a refresh and thought that I had a double post or something, lol. I saw the extra line and freaked, then I saw the revised notice and understood. Sorry! I +1 you!

Comment: Yep, I agree using a CDN can be get a lot benefits (we are a CDN company lol), but I still prefer to have a minimum version so that the first ever load on a browser, or any browser will not have to rely on a CDN especially on an mobile device.

Answer (score 2):

The functionality you need is done by jQuery's jQuery.ready.promise function.

You could extract and use only that part of the code.

```
jQuery.ready.promise = function( object ) {
if ( !readyList ) {

readyList = jQuery.Deferred();

// Catch cases where $(document).ready() is called after the
// browser event has already occurred.
if ( document.readyState !== "loading" ) {
// Handle it asynchronously to allow scripts the opportunity to delay ready
setTimeout( jQuery.ready, 1 );

// Mozilla, Opera and webkit nightlies currently support this event
} else if ( document.addEventListener ) {
// Use the handy event callback
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", DOMContentLoaded, false );

// A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
window.addEventListener( "load", jQuery.ready, false );

// If IE event model is used
} else {
// ensure firing before onload,
// maybe late but safe also for iframes
document.attachEvent( "onreadystatechange", DOMContentLoaded );

// A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
window.attachEvent( "onload", jQuery.ready );

// If IE and not a frame
// continually check to see if the document is ready
var toplevel = false;

try {
toplevel = window.frameElement == null;
} catch(e) {}

if ( document.documentElement.doScroll && toplevel ) {
doScrollCheck();
}
}
}
return readyList.promise( object );
};
```

You can see it here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js

Comment: I like this answer, needs some more testing but thank for pointing out the exact code I needed.

Comment: Since the method to check is different in different browsers, you need all these checks.
Yes, there is a lot of jquery still in here. But you should be able to extract the part that you need. And if you need help with that, just post it on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

cdn + fallback is pretty good:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Or you could pick and choose what you need from smaller libraries: http://microjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you were asking, but an alternative solution is to just include your scripts at the end of the body, just before the closing `</body>` tag. This will achieve the same result without needing to include even a cut-down version of jQuery.

The point of the document.ready function is that it will be called after the DOM is ready, i.e., after the browser has parsed all of your html and it is ready to be manipulated from JavaScript. Putting your JS code at the end of the body achieves the same effect, because the browser executes JavaScript as it encounters it while parsing the document, and when the JS is executed it can access any DOM elements that have already been parsed.

When I mentioned this idea in a comment you asked how your code would be executed, so here's a simple example:

```
// CHANGE THE FOLLOWING:

$(document).ready(function() {
    var myField = document.getElementById("someId");
    alert(myField.value);
});

// TO BE

var myField = document.getElementById("someId");
alert(myField.value);
```

It doesn't matter if the above is included inline (within a script block, though) or in an external JS file included by a script tag, as long as it is at the end of the body.

The only problem with it is that because the code is then not contained within a function it will create global variables - which as a general rule you want to avoid because if in future you were to include other external libraries they may try to define variables with the same names. You can avoid this problem by wrapping your code in an immediately invoked anonymous function expression:

```
(function() {
    var x = "these variables are not global",
        myField = document.getElementById("someId");
    alert(myField.value);

    function test() {
        alert("this function isn't global either");
    }
    test();
})();
```

Note the extra parens - the ones around the anonymous function make it a function expression rather than a function declaration (which means it doesn't need a name), and the ones at the end cause the function to be invoked immediately.

You can see a real-life example of putting JS at the end of the body just by viewing the page source on the Stack Overflow page you are reading right now.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation, that's exactly the question I asked.